# Swift AWS S3 Upload Response is 200 but no image uploaded

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, nsurlsession

I am trying to upload an image from my `iOS` app using the signed url created by the server. While performing the **S3 upload** using the signed url I'm getting `HTTP 200` response. But when I check the image `URL` from browser, I get a broken image. I think there's something wrong with my `HTTPBODY`. I'm looking for a solution **without** using `AWS sdk`.

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

.........

```
request.setValue("image/png", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("public-read", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-amz-acl")
request.setValue("*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
request.HTTPBody = params.objectForKey("imageData") as? NSData
```

I even tried encoding the data, but nothing worked.

```
let imageBase64= imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with the code ?

Comment: where you used this `let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`

Comment: I'm picking the image from Photos Album and converting the image to imageData before API call.

Answer (score 0):

can you please convert Image in to jpg and then try to upload.

if you are able to see broken image on browser it may be size issue.

please try

`let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)`

Also you can check any size restriction from s3 upload.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: are you check if any size restriction ?

Comment: if you have credential please check some time there may be some limitation.